# Is "preferred" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

If yes, does it mean "very much liked by people"?

"I'd like to sell 3,000 GDRs of Samsung Electronics **preferred**."

Comment: It's not clear what you want to say, because *"I'd like to sell 3,000 GDRs of Samsung Electronics very much liked by people"* doesn't make sense either.  Do you mean "I'd like to sell (some things) *that are* very much liked by people"?

Comment: So you mean "3,000 GDRs of Samsung Electronics" doesn't make sense, either?

Comment: I'm not clear on what *GDR* means in this context.  If it means *global depositary receipt*, then [*preferred* is a technical term in finance](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/preferredstock.asp); it does not just mean "people like it".

Comment: So we say "....preferred" or "...preferred stocks"?

Comment: Yes, stock is often left out. Preferred shares of a stock.

Comment: **preferred** there after the name of the stock is comparable to asking a bartender for "a shot of Johnny Walker *Blue*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's stock market terminology.

In the stock market, **GDR** (per [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/111913/investing-foreign-stocks-adrs-and-gdrs.asp)) stands for "global depositary receipt" and

> represents a bank certificate issued in more than one country for shares in a foreign company. The shares are held by a foreign branch of an international bank. The shares trade as domestic shares, but are offered for sale globally through the various bank branches. The term GDR is used throughout the globe and designates any foreign firm that trades on an exchange outside its home country.

Also according to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/preferredstock.asp), you have preferred stocks, which can also be **preferred shares**:

> A preferred stock is a class of ownership in a corporation that has a higher claim on its assets and earnings than common stock. Preferred shares generally have a dividend that must be paid out before dividends to common shareholders, and the shares usually do not carry voting rights.

So, the sentence could have read:

> I'd like to sell 3,000 GDRs worth of Samsung Electronics preferred shares.

However, as has been noted in a comment, **shares** can be dropped and the sentence understood without it.

Comment: This omission of the word "shares" is standard in financial discussions.